# react counter increase until input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am new to react and was making a basic counter. Logic might not be perfect but for now i want my counter to increase until the input value. Currently it decreases until 0 and increases unlimited. how can implement or bind my onChange function to onIncrease function?

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      counter: 0,
      inputText: '',
    }
  }

  // TODO: i should be able to increase only up to given input number
  onChange = (event) => {
    let inputText = event.target.value;
    this.setState({inputText});
  }

  onIncrease = () => {
      let counter = this.state.counter +1;
      this.setState({counter})
  }

  onDecrease = () => {
    if (this.state.counter > 0){
      let counter = this.state.counter -1;
      this.setState({counter})
    } 
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.counter);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2 id='s'>Counter: {this.state.counter}</h2>
        <input onChange= {this.onChange}/>
        <button onClick={this.onIncrease}>Increase</button>
        <button onClick={this.onDecrease}>Decrease</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your decrease function, you check to see that the current counter is larger than zero, before decreasing. You should implement a similar check in the increase function. E.g., check that the current counter is below the value from the input field.

A couple of more things I would do to reduce the amount of logic in the increase function to a minimum:

- In the initial state, set a "maxValue" property to Infinity
- parse the input value an int in the onChange function, and use it to update the maxValue property of the state
- Use the maxValue from the state in the increase function

```js
// in constructor:
this.state = {
  ...
  maxValue: Infinity
};

// in onChange:
this.setState({
  maxValue: parseInt(e.target.value)
});

// in increase function:
if (this.state.counter < this.state.maxValue) { 
  //increase here
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. Yes, i was aware that my logic was somewhat wrong. Now i learned to put correct logic first and then implement it)

Answer (score 1):

You can put a similar check as you have put in `onDecrease` method.

And I think one more check should be put incase the input value was more that the current counter value. May be we can change the counter to the new input value.

```
  onChange = event => {
    let inputText = event.target.value;
    if (this.state.counter > Number(inputText)) {
      this.setState({
        counter: Number(inputText),
        inputText
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ inputText });
    }
  };

  onIncrease = () => {
    if (this.state.counter < Number(this.state.inputText)) {
      let counter = this.state.counter + 1;
      this.setState({ counter });
    }
  };
```

You can add checks to user inputs too, like if a user inputs some string.

Comment: You could store the limit directly in the state as a number, instead of having to do `Number(this.state.inputText)` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You want to cap the min and max values of the count:

```
onChange = event => {
  let inputText = Number(event.target.value);
  this.setState({ inputText });
};

onIncrease = () => {
  let counter = Math.min(this.state.counter + 1, this.state.inputText);
  this.setState({ counter });
};

onDecrease = () => {
  let counter = Math.max(0, this.state.counter - 1);
  this.setState({ counter });
};
```

[image: Edit epic-benz-fqbo6]

Answer (score -1):

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      counter: 0,
      inputValue: 0,
    }
  }

  // TODO: i should be able to increase only up to given input number
  onChange = (event) => {
    let inputValue = event.target.value;
    this.setState({inputValue});
  }

  onIncrease = () => {
      if (this.state.counter < this.state.inputValue){
      let counter = this.state.counter +1;
      this.setState({counter})
  }

  onDecrease = () => {
    if (this.state.counter > 0){
      let counter = this.state.counter -1;
      this.setState({counter})
    } 
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.counter);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2 id='s'>Counter: {this.state.counter}</h2>
        <input onChange= {this.onChange}/>
        <button onClick={this.onIncrease}>Increase</button>
        <button onClick={this.onDecrease}>Decrease</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```